# Como gerar números sequenciais automaticamente com ano vigente em rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, table, sqlite3, auto-incremento, generators

Preciso que quando for criado um novo produto ele gere um numero ex: 0001/2015 numero/ano_vigente e quando mudar de ano volte ao zero.

Fiz um helper só pra dar formato ao número nas views, mas não resolve o problema da geração automática e a renovação no proximo ano.

```
def format_product_number(product_code)
 format_product = product_code[0..4]
 format_product << "/#{Time.now.year}"
 format_product
end
```

tenho um formulário com um campo:

```
@product

<%= f.label :product_number %>
<%= f.number_field :product_number %>
```

Alguém sabe um jeito de fazer isso?

Comment: Gerar automatico e add na tabela?

Comment: O banco que vc vai usar é o sqlite mesmo?

Comment: @AlexTakitani Por enquanto sim, sou novato ainda não as vantagens e desvantagens dos outros bancos.

Comment: @JeffersonAlison Gerar automático, tipo como o próprio ID, assim que o cliente clicar em create gerar o "número/ano_vigente".

Comment: Gerar o número é relativamente simples, o problema são os requisitos. É um sistema de verdade? Se sim, opera em que horários? A sequência pode ter furos? ex.: 001/2015, 003/2015 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O @AlexTakitani fez boas indagações, mas para responder rapidamente você pode armazenar isso no banco utilizando um [callback](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html):

```
    before_create :record_code_number

    private

    def record_code_number
      self.your_field_table = "#{product_code[0..4]}/#{Time.now.year}"
    end
```

Atente-se sempre ao tipo de callback utilizado, e para as validações também!

Valeuu!